# How it is possible to debugging Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException

Tags: xaml, debugging, uwp

During the methode

```
InitializeComponent()
```

in the main class of a customized control occurs the error with the follow message:¨

> Message   "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException: Der Text zu diesem Fehlercode wurde nicht gefunden.\r\n\r\nCannot create instance of type 'Uwp.UI.Control.OneNotePicker.OnenotePicker' [Line: 37 Position: 42]\r\n   at Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator, ComponentResourceLocation componentResourceLocation)\r\n   at TestEnvironment.Uwp.MainPage.InitializeCom"  string

This error is an unhandled exception and is shown with a debug break under App.g.i.cs

```
UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        };
```

It seems, there is an error during parsing the Xaml file. My question is now, how I can find exactly the row of the Xaml file, where the error occurs.

Thanks for help

Comment: The issue might be caused by a spelling mistake of the resource name that you defined in the Page.Resources or App.Resources.Please check where you are setting the resources and make sure the spelling is correct.

Comment: thanks Roy, you helped me to get the rigth trace: The risen was a wrong x:Key reference in an Xaml control to a string in the resw table.

Comment: Glad to hear that. May I convert my comment to an answer? So you could mark it and help others who are facing the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue might be caused by a spelling mistake of the resource name that you defined in the Page.Resources or App.Resources.Please check where you are setting the resources and make sure the spelling is correct.